# How to move an object to random coordinates in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'am reviewing the code for the project.

What I want to do is the following picture.
[image]

I have some questions about the project.

As a beginner, I will not have enough explanation,
but I would appreciate it if you could give it a look.

Here are the questions:

1. How do I create an object called small_star as indefinitely, as shown in the picture?
2. Currently, prefab x, y coordinate values ​​are centered on the scene.
   How do I move an object with random coordinates like a photo? And when I look at the code, I use Mathf.Cos and Mathf.Sin. What effect does it have?

I think I should implement it, but it is too much for me to do coding.
I'm a beginner. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a specific explanation.

Comment: Have you tried `Random.Range(minValue, maxValue)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that

Comment: Add in the question the code you have in the script StarAnimation (what appears in the right side of the picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont provide much information, but this may work

```
public GameObject small_star;
public float xMinBoundary;
public float yMinBoundary;
public float xMaxBoundary;
public float yMaxBoundary;

void MoveSpaceShip(){
    float randX = Random.Range (xMinBoundary, xMaxBoundary);
    float randY = Random.Range (yMinBoundary, yMaxBoundary);
    Vector2 target = new Vector2 (randX,randY)
    //Option 1
    //small_star.transform.Translate(target * Time.deltaTime);
    //Option 2
    small_star.transform.position(target)
}
```

You will need to adapt to your needs

Comment: umm... You need more information?

Comment: I dont know really how you want move the start, if instant or with a visual translation. Neither the boundaries where you want to move the GameObject. This you will need to define for the Random.Range